# how can I make a slide show repeat

Tags: javascript

I set up a slideshow for my webpage with the following script, but can't find it out how can I make it repeat. I mean I want when it go to the last photo, it will repeat to the first one again. Any one can help please:

open this link and view the code source please:
http://www.xuanyinwen.com/test2.html

Many thanks
Wayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI Neo, could you have another look for my script again, its working now: http://www.xuanyinwen.com/test2.html

not sure what script should I overrided by your line: setting.playtimer=setTimeout(function(){slideshow.showslide('next')}, 2500)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can either set the number of cycles in `displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:2500, cycles:[here], wraparound:false},` you should also try changing `persist: true`
as it will remember  the last viewed slide and recall it.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't even working as you say it is. However if it was you could add following line manually to override anything:

```
setting.playtimer=setTimeout(function(){slideshow.showslide('next')}, 2500)
```